# how to add a line in a text file using Xcode

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

I am new to programming i wanted to add a string in between paragraphs
in a text file , like using mutable string and nsfilemanager , i want
to do it programmatically in " iOS " any help would be helpful.

I want to load the text file and put a line after each paragraph like
find and replace .. find where \n is and replace it with \n\n so that
it would seperate the para's with a line . i want to do it
programatically just dont know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[mutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\n\n"];
```